# How to automate the process to select the clusters using the labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I'm new to using python and I'm working in the analyze of some data, I'm using a process extremely manual to find the clusters, first I get the labels using the method from the library:

```
labels = optics_model.labels_[optics_model.ordering_]
```

then I use the command angwhere to find the index values that have that label:

```
cluster_0 = np.argwhere(labels == 0)
```

then I print this data, use another site to clean the data and use it to select from the dataframe the rows that are from this cluster:

```
index_0 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
cluster_0 = df.iloc[index_0]
```

can someone help me automate this process?

Comment: What you've described sounds like something which is already automated. You're missing a few things - you'll need to loop over each label, and you'll need to save the clusters somehow. There's the data cleaning step, which is not very well explained. Is that the manual part? Which part are you looking for help with?

Comment: Is the cleaning part, like a said I print it put the output can't be used all the number are between [] so I use a site to remove it, this site: https://textcleaner.net/ what I'm loking for is a comand that I'm not aware that make this process

Answer (score -1):

So after some looking and testing I made it work for me using a method to add a column to the dataframe with the labels:

```
df_copy = df.assign(labels=labels)
```

then I calculated the number of clusters using this:

```
max = 0
for i in range(len(labels)):
    if max < labels[i]:
        max = labels[i]
```

then a made the necessary number of empty dataframes:

```
cluster = {}
for i in range(max):
    cluster[i] = pd.DataFrame()
```

then I just copy the data I want from the dataframe:

```
for i in range(0, max):
    cluster[i] = df_copy.loc[df_copy['labels'] == i]
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do something like the following: `cluster = dict([*df.assign(labels=labels).groupby("labels")])` or `cluster = {n: gdf for n, (_, gdf) in enumerate(df.assign(labels=labels).groupby("labels"))}`?